# Replace string with line range from another file, including modification of line range on replace

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two files of code, the first (File1) including a few lines of text to be included and the second (File2) including strings that will be replaced with a range of lines from the first file. The lines included from the first file will also need the following string appended to each of the lines when they are included in the second file (not including the quotations): " & ". In addition, a search and replace for some of the strings from the first file (File1) needs to be replaced in the output file (File3). An example of the first two files is included below.

**File1**

```
A A
B B
C C
D D
N 1 & 1 \\
Me 2 & 2 \\
Sd 3 & 3 \\
Dian 4 & 4 \\
E E
F F
G G
H H
```

**File2**

```
D D
C C
B B
A A
str_text1
H H
G G
F F
E E
```

The example below is what I would like the new output file (File3) to have. It is imperative File1 and File2 are not overwritten, and everything must be restructured into the new file File3.

**File3**

```
D D
C C
B B
A A
 & N 1 & 1 \\
 & $\m$ 2 & 2 \\
 & $\sig$ 3 & 3 \\
 & $\dian{x}$ 4 & 4 \\
H H
G G
F F
E E
```

I would like this to be a one liner inside of a shell script, and below is an example of what I have so far. I am not sure how to do the last substitution into the same one liner, however as a second one liner it is very simple. If these could be combined, I would appreciate that greatly.

**Code1**

```
sed -e 's/str_text1/ \& $(sed -n 5,8p File1.txt)/' \
    < File2.txt > File3.txt
```

**Code1 Output*** Fails to include the lines. Use of double quotes results in error: `` sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command ``.

```
D D
C C
B B
A A
 & $(sed -n 5,8p File1.txt)
H H
G G
F F
E E
```

**Code2** Simple for search and replace and works fine as is. This is replacing some of the strings in the first column from File1 in the new File3 file.

```
    sed -i -e 's/Me/$\m$/g' \
        -i -e 's/Sd/$\sig$/g' \
        -i -e 's/Dian/$\dian{x}$/g' \
        File3.txt
```

Comment: wrt `I would like this to be a one liner inside of a shell script` - asking for a one-liner tells us you care more above brevity than anything that really matters in software (e.g. clarity, portability, efficiency, robustness, maintainability, etc.) and so it's usually a bad idea to ever ask for a on-liner as it discourages us from providing a good solution as you'll probably end up accepting a worse but briefer solution. Additionally, if this piece of code is going to be inside a shell script as you say, then it's hard to imagine why you'd care how many lines it's on.

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand correctly here is the final output you are looking after executing code 1 & 2 :

```
D D
C C
B B
A A
 & N 1 & 1 \\
 & $\m$ 2 & 2 \\
 & $\sig$ 3 & 3 \\
 & $\dian{x}$ 4 & 4 \\
H H
G G
F F
E E
```

I suggest using a one line mixture of awk with gsub for search and replace function and asked.

```
    #CODE1 : oneliner
    awk -v a="$(awk 'NR==5, NR==8' File1.txt  | sed -ie 's/\\/#/g' | sed -ie 's/&/@/g' | sed 's/^/ @ &/')" '{ gsub(/str_text1/,a); print }' File2.txt > File3.txt
    #CODE2 : oneliner
    sed -i -e 's/Me/$\\\m$/g' -i -e 's/Sd/$\\\sig$/g' -i -e 's/Dian/\$\\\dian{x}$/g' -i -e 's/@/\&/g' -i -e 's/#/\\/g' File3.txt
    cat File3.txt
```

Explanation :

**CODE 1**

Same as `sed -n 5,8p File1.txt` but instead put the whole result in awk variable so it will be used next by the gsub utility `awk -v a="$(awk 'NR==5, NR==8' File1.txt)"`

I prefer using **awk** instead of **sed** for getting range of line from a text file `awk 'NR==5, NR==8' File1.txt`

Will replace the special characters \ and & respectively by **#** and **@** ; because for the next command (awk) \ and & are specials chars `sed -ie 's/\\/#/g' | sed -ie 's/&/@/g'`

Replace **str_text1** by the content of the variable **a** `gsub(/str_text1/,a); print`

***CODE 2 :***

I have added some to your command so it will match the wanted output `sed -i -e 's/Me/$\\\m$/g' -i -e 's/Sd/$\\\sig$/g' -i -e 's/Dian/\$\\\dian{x}$/g'`

Replace back the characters that we used as an escape chars : @-> & ; # -> \ `sed -i -e 's/@/\&/g' -i -e 's/#/\\/g'`